# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: bot is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

**main.py**

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('moon '),
                   case_insensitive=True)

my_secret = os.environ['token']
for file in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        name = file[:-3]
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")

for utility in os.listdir("./cogs/utility"):
    if utility.endswith(".py"):
        name = utility[:-3]
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.utility.{name}")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('  {} está online!'.format(bot.user.name))


bot.run(my_secret)
```

**ping.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Utility(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx, bot):
        await ctx.send('A Lua está com {}ms'.format(bot.latency * 100))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Utility(bot))
```

when I use the ping command, I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: bot is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Yes, because you are missing `bot`. Why did you set it as a required argument? Simply say `self.bot.latency` and you do not need `bot` as a required argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 errors in ping.py:

1. You dont need argument in ping command.
2. It should be (self.bot.latency) instead of (bot.latency)
3. For converting second into microseconds in ping command, replace (self.bot.latency * 100) with (self.bot.latency * 1000)

This ping.py program should work:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Utility(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('A Lua está com {}ms'.format(self.bot.latency * 1000))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Utility(bot))
```